# disable custom error messages and display detailed information about any runtime error

Tags: asp.net, .net

So in one of my classes we are being asked to write code to do the following:

"disable custom error messages and display detailed information about any runtime error "

in the web.config file.

I have tried many things, and also tried doing some research, but I cannot figure out the code to do BOTH at the same time. customErrors mode ="Off" will disable it. I cant figure out what to use to ALSO then show detailed information when a run time error occurs.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of detailed information, you could store all Try Catch exception messages and where they occurred either in a Session or Cache variable. If that variable is-Not Nothing at the end of the process simply display the compiled message as an "Alert" using a register start-up script call. You can give the error message and where it occurred. Also if you make this a system wide method, you can make it turn of and on through a setup option.